# FB API parameter error: The parameter ad_reached_countries is required

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to get the FB ads through the Graph API using the code below,

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'app_id',
      'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v19.0',
      //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);

// Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken instance.
//   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

$params = array(
        "access_token" => "accesstokenhere",
        "ad_reached_countries" => "US",
        "search_terms" => "bags"
);
try {
    // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
    // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
    $response = $fb->get('/ads_archive', 
                        'accesstokenhere', 
                        array (
                            'ad_reached_countries'   => 'US',
                            'search_terms'           => 'bags',
                            ), 
                        );
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();

dd($me);
```

but it gave me

> The parameter ad_reached_countries is required

I tried concatenating the `$params` variable at the end of the GET call but still it gives the same error message.

When I also placed `ad_reached_countries` after the `ads_archive`, it gave me `Invalid parameter` error.  How would I properly place the `ad_reached_countries` and/or other paramters when searching for ads.

Comment: `// Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.` - absolutely not what you are trying to do there ... so I suppose this is code copy&pasted from somewhere else, that you are now trying to modify? Looks like this is their "normal" Graph API PHP SDK you are using there? Then you should probably look into actually using the Business SDK, https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk

Comment: @CBroe i am trying to get ads_archive and yes I just copied and pasted this one but it seems I am in the right direction, however when I got the error it seems I was not. which field or class should I be using when I want to search for the ads, I skimmed on the fields and I dont see a specific class to use for it.

Comment: `ad_reached_countries` is supposed to be an array, so try `'ad_reached_countries'   => ['US'],`

Comment: @CBroe i tried it like this `$fb->get('/ads_archive', 'tokenhere', array('ad_reached_countries' => 'US'));` still it gives the `(#100) The parameter ad_reached_countries is required.` error. :( I'm desperate please help

Comment: That is the same format as before, only you now removed the `search_terms` parameter. Hardly what I actually suggested. You should replace the `'US'` with `['US']`, nothing else.

Comment: @CBroe same error is displayed. $fb->get('/ads_archive', 'toknhere', array('ad_reached_countries' => ['US']));

Comment: I would try to get the request to work in Graph API Explorer first, then you can still see how to convert it into SDK compatible code afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe also did that and it looks like this `ads_archive?ad_reached_countries=US&search_terms=bags`  the only problem i have is converting it to php code so that it properly fetches the same result

Comment: And passing exactly that directly as first parameter, and leaving the actual parameters empty, doesn't work?

Comment: @CBroe this error is displayed `Unable to convert response from Graph to a GraphNode because the response looks like a GraphEdge. Try using GraphNodeFactory::makeGraphEdge() instead.` after i replaced the call with `$response = $fb->get('ads_archive?ad_reached_countries=US&search_terms=bags', 'tokenhere');`

Comment: That is likely due to `$me = $response->getGraphUser();`, which of course makes little sense, when you are not actually requesting any _user_ object, but something completely different. You probably want something like this, https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.x/docs/reference/GraphEdge.md#facebookgraphnodesgraphedge

Comment: @CBroe my God, thank you so much. how can I reward you for the answer? kindly post an answer and I will accept it as the correct one. finally i got what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If passing the parameters as an array doesn't create the actually needed request URL, then specifying the full URL including the parameters in the first `get` method argument, should work.

And since you are not requesting a user object any more, the `$me = $response->getGraphUser();` needs to be replaced with something more appropriate as well. Using `$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();`, you should afterwards be able to loop over the result, and access the individual GraphNodes.